The episode where Archer complains about honeydew, the melon
Which episode of Archer is the one where he gripes about how honeydew, the melon, is always served with cantaloupe?
I don't usually like to ask episode identification questions here, but I didn't have luck on Google. Search results are entirely about Bunsen Honeydew. Omitting Bunsen leaves a song named Hero by somebody named Honeydew. Omitting Hero leaves figuratively zero results. I couldn't find a script or anything.
I'm pretty sure I remember it being in one of the two most recent seasons.

I think you're confusing it with Bojack Horseman. From episode 7 in season 2:

Bojack: Goddamn it, honeydew?! Jesus, why does cantaloupe think every time it gets invited to a party, it can bring along its dumb friend honeydew? You don't get a plus-one, cantaloupe!

It's a running joke that Bojack hates honeydew. He said it in several episodes.

Quickly answered. Wonderful. But that one was pretty easy to find. ;)

@AbhishekAggrawal True, it was fresh in my memory. I watched the first couple of seasons recently.

Oh man, I totally was. No wonder I couldn't find it. I was watching Bojack Horseman at the same time as the latest season of Archer. My memories seriously contain a made up clip of Archer saying those words. Ha, thanks!
